# InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback):logits and labels must be broadcastable: logits_size=[183,2] labels_size=[20,2]

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

```
This is a learning-based rna and disease prediction code using cnn that I downloaded from github. The output is accuracy and auc values, but the result is very unstable (occasionally 0.3, occasionally 0.8). 

 



I don't know what the reason is, but the division of training set and verification set in this article is a self-defined function, so I want to try 10 cross-verification. However, when I write the cross-validation code, the problem as shown in the title appears.
```

This is the code that divides the training set and the verification set in the source code.

```
def get_data(args):

   input_data, input_label = dh.get_samples(args)
   input_data = standard_scale(input_data)
   dev_sample_percentage = args.dev_percentage
   test_sample_percentage = args.test_percentage
   x = np.array(input_data)

   Randomly shuffle data
   np.random.seed(10)
   shuffle_indices = np.random.permutation(np.arange(len(input_label)))
   input_data = [x[i] for i in shuffle_indices]
   input_label = [input_label[i] for i in shuffle_indices]
   dev_sample_index = -2 * int(dev_sample_percentage * float(len(input_label)))
   test_sample_index = -1 * int(test_sample_percentage * float(len(input_label)))
   x_train, x_dev, test_data = input_data[:dev_sample_index],     input_data[dev_sample_index:test_sample_index], input_data[test_sample_index:]
   y_train, y_dev, test_label = input_label[:dev_sample_index],   input_label[dev_sample_index:test_sample_index], input_label[test_sample_index:]

   return x_train, x_dev, test_data, y_train, y_dev, test_label
```

This is my modified code.

```
def get_data(args):

   input_data, input_label = dh.get_samples(args)
   input_data = standard_scale(input_data)
   dev_sample_percentage = args.dev_percentage
   test_sample_percentage = args.test_percentage
   x = np.array(input_data)

   y = np.array(input_label)
   kf = KFold(n_splits=10)
   d = kf.split(x)
   for train_idx, test_idx in d:
      x_train = x[train_idx]
      x_dev = x[test_idx]
   l=kf.split(y)
   for train_idx ,test_idx in l:
      y_train=y[train_idx]
      y_dev=y[test_idx]
   test_sample_index = -1 * int(test_sample_percentage * float(len(input_label)))
   test_data=input_data[test_sample_index:]
   test_lable=input_label[test_sample_index:]
   return x_train,x_dev,y_train, y_dev,test_data,test_lable
```

[This is a screenshot of the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AygbD.png)

This is the complete code of this part.

```
 #! /usr/bin/env python

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
import argparse
import data_helpers as dh
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve
from sklearn import metrics
from tensorflow.contrib import learn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sklearn.preprocessing as prep
from sklearn.metrics import average_precision_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold





def parse_args():
   parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Run CNN.")
   ## the input file
   ##disease-gene relationships and miRNA-gene relatiohships
   parser.add_argument('--input_disease_miRNA', nargs='?', default='..\..\data\CNN\disease-miro-1024-sigmoid.csv',
                  help='Input disease_gene_relationship file')

   parser.add_argument('--input_label',nargs = '?',default='..\..\data\CNN\label.csv',
                  help='sample label')
   parser.add_argument('--batch_size', nargs='?', default=64,
                  help = 'number of samples in one batch')
   parser.add_argument('--training_epochs', nargs='?', default=1,
                  help= 'number of epochs in SGD')
   parser.add_argument('--display_step', nargs='?', default=10)
   parser.add_argument('--test_percentage', nargs='?', default=0.1,
                  help='percentage of test samples')
   parser.add_argument('--dev_percentage', nargs='?', default=0.1,
                  help='percentage of validation samples')
   parser.add_argument('--L2_norm', nargs='?', default=0.001,
                  help='percentage of validation samples')
   parser.add_argument('--keep_prob', nargs='?', default=0.5,
                  help='keep_prob when using dropout option')
   parser.add_argument('--optimizer', nargs='?', default=tf.train.AdamOptimizer,
                  help='optimizer for learning weights')
   parser.add_argument('--learning_rate', nargs='?', default=1e-3,
                  help='learning rate for the SGD')

   return parser.parse_args()
def standard_scale(X_train):

   preprocessor = prep.StandardScaler().fit(X_train)
   X_train = preprocessor.transform(X_train)

   return X_train
def weight_variable(shape):
   initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev= 0.1)
   weights = tf.Variable(initial)

   return weights
def bias_variable(shape):
   initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape = shape)
   return tf.Variable(initial)
def conv2d(x,W):
   return tf.nn.conv2d(x,W,strides=[1,1,1,1], padding= "VALID")
def max_pool_2(x, W):
   return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize = W, strides= [1,10,1,1], padding= "VALID")


def get_data(args):

   input_data, input_label = dh.get_samples(args)
   input_data = standard_scale(input_data)
   dev_sample_percentage = args.dev_percentage
   test_sample_percentage = args.test_percentage
   x = np.array(input_data)

   y = np.array(input_label)
   kf = KFold(n_splits=10)
   d = kf.split(x)
   for train_idx, test_idx in d:
      x_train = x[train_idx]
      x_dev = x[test_idx]
   l=kf.split(y)
   for train_idx ,test_idx in l:
      y_train=y[train_idx]
      y_dev=y[test_idx]
   test_sample_index = -1 * int(test_sample_percentage * float(len(input_label)))
   test_data=input_data[test_sample_index:]
   test_lable=input_label[test_sample_index:]
   return x_train,x_dev,y_train, y_dev,test_data,test_lable


   # # Randomly shuffle data
   # np.random.seed(10)
   # shuffle_indices = np.random.permutation(np.arange(len(input_label)))
   # input_data = [x[i] for i in shuffle_indices]
   # input_label = [input_label[i] for i in shuffle_indices]
   # dev_sample_index = -2 * int(dev_sample_percentage * float(len(input_label)))
   # test_sample_index = -1 * int(test_sample_percentage * float(len(input_label)))
   # x_train, x_dev, test_data = input_data[:dev_sample_index], input_data[dev_sample_index:test_sample_index], input_data[test_sample_index:]
   # y_train, y_dev, test_label = input_label[:dev_sample_index], input_label[dev_sample_index:test_sample_index], input_label[test_sample_index:]
   #
   # return x_train, x_dev, test_data, y_train, y_dev, test_label


def deepnn(x, keep_prob, args):
   with tf.name_scope('reshape'):
      x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 1024, 1, 1])

   with tf.name_scope('conv_pool'):
      filter_shape = [4, 1, 1, 4]

      W_conv = weight_variable(filter_shape)
      b_conv = bias_variable([4])
      h_conv = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x, W_conv) + b_conv)
      h_pool = tf.nn.max_pool(h_conv, ksize = [1, 4, 1, 1], strides= [1,4,1,1], padding= "VALID")

      # filter_shape2 = [4,1,4,4]
      # W_conv2 = weight_variable(filter_shape2)
      # b_conv2 = bias_variable([4])
      # h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
      # h_pool2 = tf.nn.max_pool(h_conv2, ksize=[1,4,1,1], strides= [1,4,1,1],padding="VALID")

      regula = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(args.L2_norm)
      h_input1 = tf.reshape(h_pool,[-1, 255 * 4])
      W_fc1 = weight_variable([255* 4, 50])

      b_fc1 = bias_variable([50])
      h_input2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_input1, W_fc1) + b_fc1)
      h_keep = tf.nn.dropout(h_input2, keep_prob)
      W_fc2 = weight_variable([50, 2])
      b_fc2 = bias_variable([2])
      h_output = tf.matmul(h_keep, W_fc2) + b_fc2
      regularizer = regula(W_fc1) + regula(W_fc2)
      return h_output, regularizer


def main(args):
   with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
      x_train, x_dev, test_data, y_train, y_dev, test_label = get_data(args)
      input_data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1024])
      input_label = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2])
      keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
      y_conv, losses = deepnn(input_data, keep_prob, args)
      y_res = tf.nn.softmax(y_conv)
      with tf.name_scope('loss'):
         cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=y_conv, labels=input_label)
      cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)
      los = cross_entropy + losses
      with tf.name_scope('optimizer'):
         optimizer = args.optimizer
         learning_rate = args.learning_rate
         train_step = optimizer(learning_rate).minimize(los)
         # optimizer = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate= 0.02, momentum=)
         # train_step = optimizer.minimize(cross_entropy)
      with tf.name_scope('accuracy'):
         predictions = tf.argmax(y_conv, 1)
         correct_predictions = tf.equal(predictions, tf.argmax(input_label, 1))
         correct_predictions = tf.cast(correct_predictions, tf.float32)
      accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(correct_predictions)

      batch_size = args.batch_size
      num_epochs = args.training_epochs
      display_step = args.display_step
      k_p = args.keep_prob
      with tf.Session() as sess:
            sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

            batches = dh.batch_iter(list(zip(x_train, y_train)), batch_size, num_epochs)

            for i, batch in enumerate(batches):
               x_batch, y_batch = zip(*batch)# 按batch把数据拿进来

               train_step.run(feed_dict={input_data: x_batch, input_label: y_batch, keep_prob: k_p})

               if i % display_step == 0:

                     loss = sess.run(los, feed_dict={input_data: x_train, input_label: y_train, keep_prob: 1.0})
                     #print('after training loss = %f' % loss)
                     y_predict = sess.run(y_res, feed_dict={input_data: x_dev, input_label: y_dev, keep_prob: 1.0})[:, 1]

                     loss = sess.run(los, feed_dict={input_data: x_dev, input_label: y_dev, keep_prob: 1.0})
                     #print('test loss = %f' % loss)

                     false_positive_rate1, true_positive_rate1, thresholds1 = roc_curve(np.array(y_dev)[:, 1], y_predict)
                     roc_auc1 = auc(false_positive_rate1, true_positive_rate1)
                     # print(roc_auc1)
            ###print(accuracy.eval(feed_dict={input_data: x_train, input_label:y_train, keep_prob: 1.0}))
            print('accuracy=',accuracy.eval(feed_dict={input_data: test_data, input_label: test_label, keep_prob: 1.0}))

            y_predict = sess.run(y_res, feed_dict={input_data: test_data, input_label: test_label, keep_prob: 1.0})[:, 1]
            false_positive_rate1, true_positive_rate1, thresholds1 = roc_curve(np.array(test_label)[:, 1], y_predict)
            roc_auc1 = auc(false_positive_rate1, true_positive_rate1)
            print('roc_auc1=',roc_auc1)

            # plt.figure()
            # lw=2
            # plt.title("ROC curve of %s (AUC = %.4f)")
            # plt.xlabel("False Positive Rate")
            # plt.ylabel("True Positive Rate")
            # plt.plot(false_positive_rate1 , true_positive_rate1)  # use pylab to plot x and y
            # plt.show()  # show the plot on the screen
            #
            # plt.show()


            # np.savetxt("result_fp_tp_md_aver.txt", roc_curve(np.array(test_label)[:, 1], y_predict))
            # precision, recall ,_ = precision_recall_curve(np.array(test_label)[:, 1], y_predict)
            #  #
            # average_precision = average_precision_score(np.array(test_label)[:, 1], y_predict)
            #  #
            # print('Average precision-recall score: {0:0.2f}'.format(average_precision))
            # y_predict[y_predict >= 0.5] = 1
            # y_predict[y_predict < 0.5] = 0
            # print(y_predict)
            # print(metrics.f1_score(np.array(test_label)[:, 1], y_predict))
            # np.savetxt("precision_aver.txt", precision)
            # np.savetxt("recall_aver.txt", recall)
if __name__ == '__main__':
   args = parse_args()
   main(args)
```

please help me!!!  thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it seems you have used tensorflow.contrib which has been deprecated. Infact, the code belongs to Tf1.x which will by default cause many Runtime Errors. From Tensorflow 2.x onwards you need to use Keras High level api.

Regarding the error **Logits and Labels Must Be Broadcastable** , the reason behind it is the dimensions of the logits and labels are not matching.

Use the SparseCategoricalCrossentropy loss function . The SparseCategoricalCrossentropy loss function can handle integer-encoded labels and does not require one-hot encoding.

This is a standard error and a couple more steps are enclosed in this [Document here.](https://saturncloud.io/blog/understanding-the-logits-and-labels-must-be-broadcastable-error-in-tensorflow-rnn/)